# Swift Trimming String

Tags: swift, trim

I am trying to trim a string so that i am left with everything on the right side of a colon in Swift.

For example

> "Sally: Hello My Name is Sally"

Becomes

> "Hello My Name is Sally"

What would the trim function be?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let str = "Sally: Hello My Name is Sally"
let output = str.componentsSeparatedByString(": ").last!

print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Whilst another answer has suggested using `componentsSeparatedByString(_:)` and accessing its `last` element, this is not foolproof, since the string may be something like `Sally: Hello: My Name is Sally`. In this case, the expected result would be `Hello: My Name is Sally`, but the actual result turns out to be `My Name is Sally`. A way to fix this would be to simply remove the first element of the separated array, and to join the remaining array back.

```
let str = "Sally: Hello: My Name is Sally"
let separated = str.componentsSeparatedByString(": ").dropFirst()
let output = separated.joinWithSeparator(": ")
```

Comment: Your code does *not* produce `"Hello: My Name is Sally"`. The colon is missing.